# Generate multiple HTML files from variables

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

I'm working on a site which has to generate a page for each country (the only differences between those pages are the meta-tags, the `title` and an `img` tag). Doing so manually is not very efficient for me because every time I have to change something in the template, I have to do the same with every `.html` file of the page of each country.

I heard that I could use gulp.js for this but I'm not pretty sure if I can or how.

Basically, I've to generate 12 `.html` documents like this:

```
<head>
  <title>-country title-</title>
  <meta name="description" content="-country description-">
</head>
<body>
  <img src="-country-img-" />
</body>
```

Any advice on this problem, or another possible solution?

Comment: This is trivial using one server side executable language file and a template to output dependent on url. Must they be static `.html` files?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do this on the serverside?

Comment: @charlietfl they must be static `.html` files, that's correct
@adeneo I really dunno. I specialize in the front-end and I only worked with the server-side once =O

Comment: @GonzaloDiazAilan There's nothing wrong with making static pages ahead of time.  In fact, there are a lot of advantages depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @GonzaloDiazAilan Take a look at bundlers like WebPack.  Pick a template language, generate pages on the fly, etc.  You can do this with JavaScript/Node.js.  No need to change your server.

Comment: If it were me, I'd use a serverside language, any serverside language, to create those tags on the fly based on the url's, or even the users IP, or whatever you want.

Comment: @adeneo Sure, and if nothing changes on the page you'll be wasting a ton of CPU, regenerating the same page over and over again.  Sometimes generating up front is the right solution.  If you're only templating your site, generating up-front, then you can use any static hosting (like nice CDNs) for hosting your site.  With such excellent support for modern JavaScript in browsers, and the fact that search engines run JavaScript these days, the option of going static is appealing for more and more situations.

Comment: @Brad - That's what cache is for

Comment: @adeneo Sure, that's another option, and in that case what you're proposing really isn't a whole lot different, except that your solution still requires a server running your dynamic language.  Going static has no such requirement.

Comment: Whatever floats your goat. I'd much raher have a few lines of code in a Node or PHP server that outputs the correct tags based on URL, rather than 300 static .html files, but that's just me I suppose. Some people like maintenance nightmares.

Comment: @adeneo Who said anything about 300 static HTML files?  He has 12.  **12.**  And, what you're talking about and what I'm talking about are no difference from a maintenance perspective.  You'll have a few lines of code in Node.js or PHP that cranks out pages.  The only difference, when I run my deploy command, it'll grind out that HTML once and stick it on my CDN.  When you run your deploy command, you'll copy over your scripts to your PHP hosting.  Also, better make sure your Node.js and PHP builds are up-to-date.  My maintenance effectively ends at deployment.

Comment: Sure, I'm really not in the mood to argue about trivial things, but if you think writing code that generates 12 static `.html` files that you upload to your server is the way to go, good for you. I'll still stick with my Node server that creates whatever content I want based on the URL, and is cached

Comment: My partner (which is the responsible for the server-side) is out of office today. I'd prefer to use something I can try without his help. There's any templating tool I could use for this so I could generate the static files up front?

Comment: @GonzaloDiazAilan There are tons.  I've used Hexo before but didn't like it because of some of the extra crap it adds.  Metalsmith is a popular choice but probably requires more setup.  You could simply write a basic Node.js script to run Mustache templates and output HTML for you.  Lots of choices... experiment with a couple and see what works best for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used [this article](http://tompennington.co.uk/generating-multiple-static-html-pages-with-gulp-and-handlebars/) that solves the problem using **gulp.js** + **handlebars.js**.

This is my `gulpfile.js` in case you are wondering how I did it:

```
gulp.task('pages', function() {
for(var i=0; i<countries.length; i++) {
    var country = countries[i],
        fileName = country.filename.replace(/ +/g, '-').toLowerCase();

        console.log(country.filename);

    gulp.src('countries-template.handlebars')
        .pipe(handlebars(country))
        .pipe(rename(fileName + ".html"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/countries'));
}
gulp.src('countries-template.handlebars')
    .pipe(handlebars(countries[0]))
    .pipe(rename("index.ejs"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
})
```

And this is my `countries-config.json` in case you want to see the `.json` file:

```
[{
"name": "Argentina",
"filename": "argentina",
"slug": "arg"
},{
"name": "Mexico",
"filename": "mexico",
"slug": "mex"
},{
"name": "Chile",
"filename": "chile",
"slug": "chi"
},{
"name": "Bolivia",
"filename": "bolivia",
"slug": "bol"
}, [etc...]
]
```

I won't show my `countries-template.handlebars` because it's pretty huge but I can assure this method worked for me flawlessly

Thanks all of you for your help!